# Как использовать условные конструкции в регулярных выражениях .NET

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

В регулярных выражениях есть такая штука как "условные конструкции", имеет такой синтаксис:

```
(?(subpattern)yes|no)
```

Вроде как все просто. Если находится subpattern то выполняется subpattern **yes** если нет - subpattern **no**.

У меня есть выражение:

```
10-5*(-2)
```

Хочу от него:

```
10
-
5
*
(
-2
)
```

Тоесть если встречается `(` и после число с минусом то нужно минус оставить вместе с числом.

Как-бы все логично. Если встречаеться `\(\-` то мне надо `\-\d+` если нет то `\d+`. (Каждый из этих subpattern работает так как мне нужно)
Слепил я это все к куче:

```
(?(\(\-)\-\d+|\d+)
```

Я может не правильно понимаю эту конструкцию, или просто, как обычно, туплю, но оно не работает. Всегда срабатывает subpattern **no**.

В целом задача более сложная, я все это привел только к тому что у меня не получается. Выражение для парсинга может быть любой сложности. К применению мое тестовое выражение:

`(sin(180/180.00*pi)^2-sin(180.00/180*pi))*50.00*(-10.5)`

Comment: Я бы такое парсил без регулярок

Comment: @tym32167 , это упрощанный вариант. Спросил только то, что меня интересует, что у меня не выходит. Выражение для парсинга может выглядеть следующим образом: 
(sin(180/180.00*pi)^2-sin(180.00/180*pi))*50*(-10.5)

Comment: @v.slobodzian: Используйте [алгоритм сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) и не морочьте нам голову. Рекурсивные структуры регулярками не разбираются.

Comment: @ВVladD,  принципе я уже решил как исправить мою проблему алгоритмически. Но вопрос не в том как мне в целом решить мою задачу, а в том как заставить эту регулярку работать. Меня интересует как же блин эти альтернативные конструкции работают.. засело в голову и вот уже целый день мучаюсь.

Comment: @BVlaD, а за "алгоритм сортировочной станции" больше спасибо! Я обязательно почитаю об этом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выражение `(?(\(\-)\-\d+|\d+)` не "срабатывает", потому что шаблон в условии (`\(\-`) используется как если бы он был в блоке "утвердительного" предварительного блока просмотра вперёд. Так как первый ожидаемый символ — это `(`, первая альтернатива (`\-\d+`) никогда не найдёт совпадение, так как начинается на `-`.

Если хотите найти совпадение с использованием такой "условной" конструкции, поместите открывающую скобку в блок предварительного просмотра назад - [`(?((?<=\()-)-\d+|\d+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%28%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%28%29-%29-%5cd%2b%7c%5cd%2b%29&i=10-5*%28-2%29).

Вообще, это выражение — синоним более простого выражения [`(?:(?<=\()-)?\d+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%28%29-%29%3f%5cd%2b&i=10-5*%28-2%29):

- `(?:(?<=\()-)?` - знак `-`, 1 или 0 повторений (т.е. опционален), и только если перед ним находится `(`
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Это именно то, что я хотел узнать.